# Postgresql encoding while creating database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, utf-8, utf-16

I'm setting up a database in postgresql env and while the only UTF encoding I get is UTF-8, i'm facing an issue when trying to create a table from node.js.

The issue is that the strings that I pass from javascript as the column names are encoded in UTF-16 and the postgresql trim them because its too long for its UTF-8 encoding.

While googling and searching under the postgresql/pgadmin directory, I found a folder called encodings which has utf-16 encoding script in it.
The thing is, that under database encoding in pgadmin I can't choose UTF-16.
is there any other way to choose UTF-16 encoding or maybe make the column name string size much larger?

Comment: Shouldn't the driver handle that? Java strings are also UTF-16 and I have never had to configure anything special with Postgres and the JDBC driver

Comment: Usually you should not care about internal encoding of Javascript. But: did you tried and you have problem? Often is it quicker to do a short test instead of asking and waiting for an answer. Plus: you may see other problems about integrating all things.

Comment: I havent use jdbc driver, ill give it a try. and for the internal encoding it will damage the string im trying to use.

Comment: Is this is an issue with column names or is it an issue with string values in the data? Can you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the db setup and the js code you use?

Comment: Columns names @Bergi